# How to create n cells in excel

Tags: excel

[image]

Basically, I want to to enter a number like 7 and get 7 cells in one column that are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 (my imgur picture shows what I want to do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **A2** enter:

```
=IF(ROWS($1:1)>$D$2,"",ROWS($1:1))
```

and copy downward.  If we change the value in **D7**, the number of filled cells in column **A** will grow or shrink.

Answer (score 1):

In excel there is a "Series" feature that does something similar to what you want

1. Type the number 7 in a cell
2. Select the Cell
3. On "home" tab under "editing" click "Fill"

[image]

4. Select "Series"
5. In the popup menu select Series in: "Columns" Type "Linear" Step Value:"-1" Stop Value "0" then click ok

[image]